# flutter data not retrieved from firestore when using stream

Tags: flutter, listview, google-cloud-firestore, stream

```
DatabaseService databaseService = new DatabaseService();
Stream questionsSnapshot;
```

so Im using a stream and and a database service to retrieve data (questions and answers of a quiz) to my listView builder
the called function from database service is

```
getAquizData(String quizId) async{
  return await Firestore.instance
      .collection("quiz")
      .document(quizId)
      .collection("questionReponses")
      .snapshots();
     
}
```

the init state function

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    databaseService.getAquizData(widget.quizId).then((value){
      questionsSnapshot = value;
    
      setState(() {});
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

my listViewBuilder

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        // an appbar
        ) ,
        body: Container(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            StreamBuilder(
    stream: questionsSnapshot,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
    return snapshot.data == null
    ? Container(child: Text("empty"),) :  ListView.builder(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
    itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
    itemBuilder: (context,index){
    return QuizPlayTile(
    questionModel: getQuestionModelFromDatasnapshot(
    snapshot.data.documents[index]),
    index: index,
    );
    });
    },
            )


            ],)
        )
    );
  }
}
```

when running it just show the word empty for a second and then it shows questions without answers

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4CS4.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use stream builder without calling it in `initState` method. Following code works for me. user quizStreamer in build method.

```
quizStreamer(){
   return StreamBuilder(
    stream: Firestore.instance
        .collection('quiz')
        .document(quizId)
        .collection('questionReponses')
        .snapshots(),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      //loadWidgets method takes snapshot and render defined widgets
      return loadWidgets(snapshot);
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: loaadwidgets methode not defined

Comment: @guru895 you have to define loadWidgets method and handle snapshot using your business logic :-) You can name it whatever you want.